# Create a dynamic Products page with just html/css?

Tags: html, css

Hi basically i want to have one html page that is the "products" page, and then just have the site navigation link correspond to a certain brand. I want it to look and function like any normal shopping site say a clothes site where you choose filters and it will show only clothes for that colour or brand and remove everything else, after a quick google it seems stuff like this is done in jquery and javascript etc. is it possible to do in just html/css?

I know C++ but it doesn't seem like its really suited for web dev.

I was also thinking maybe i could do this with a google custom search engine.

Just tell me straight if im out of luck and will just have to spend time learning some language/framework. Thanks.

Comment: No, you will definitely need Javascript to make it dynamic and work with databases and such. unless its a spoof site, then sure, you can do it with HTML and CSS.

Comment: C++ would be kind of overkill for what you want. Could learn some kind of libary/framework such as React,Angular, etc which can give you the ability to change or filter data on a page as you please. To answer your question, it really isn't ideal to create what you want using just pure html/css

Answer (score 0):

No isn't possible without jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, i did it myself, so the answer would be: "yes it is possible".
However, extremely hard.

You can create the .html page using file creation and file writing.
and you can write to that file (just like any other text file) with fwrite or something like that (c++ function).

you can do it "dynamic", but all calculation would be on the c++ side with tons of if statements, but at the end? => you'll write the format of an html page:

```
<html><header><body>...
```

something like this:

```
fwrite("<html>\n",$fp);
fwrite("<head>\n",$fp);
....
```

once again... possible, but hard.